# I'm having trouble with the API connection, with the HTTP (POST) method

Tags: mysql, macos, express, authentication, http

So I built an auth system (login/register) system using express.js and mysql on the MVC model. But I'm having trouble with the API connection, particularly the HTTP (POST) method. So I got two modules, under routers folder, for both login and register routes and I have an additional module for the mysql connection.

I'm using thunderclient because of tech issues with postman to test the API. In my routes, I have messages in the code that read successful and unsuccessful login. Basically I'm trying to make sure the user authentication system works in the backend with Node.js/Express.js and MySQL. I think I did everything right in my code, my server is & running, it is connected to my DB.

I will copy/paste the route for register router here and upload a screenshot of the error connection message I got, but if you need to see the rest of my files, I will provide the link to my Git repo.

Please let me know what you think, thank you.

https://github.com/remoteconn-7891/ProjectVirtual

````
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// Route & middleware for registering users using HTTP POST method 
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
const { email, password } = req.body;

connection.query('SELECT * FROM user_auth_table', (err, rows, fields) => {
    if (!err)
    res.send(rows);
    else
    console.log(err);
})
const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(12);
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      if(!isValid(email)) return res.status(400).send({error:"invalid email"})
      if(!isValid(password)) return res.status(400).send({error:"invalid password"})
      return res.status(200).json({message:"Successfully created an account"})
        res.redirect('/profile');

    if (password.length < 8) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Password must contain at least 8 characters"
        })
      }
// Implement Email Regex
    function isEmail(email) {
        const emailFormat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+(?<!^[0-9]*)@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/;
        if (email !== '' && email.match(emailFormat)) { return true; }

}

 }), 
 module.exports = router```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8XAD.png)

[enter image description here][1]

I tried debugging and testing for the past several days. I ran 'node server.js, which is my entry point file for Express and got no error messages in my cmd. I ran 'npm start' and still no errors. My mysql db is connected as well, so that's not an issue. It's entirely possible there's something wrong in the code for one my MVC modules or something I'm not importing/exporting. PS I'm using VSC & on a Mac


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOFS0.png
````

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are misusing the express.Router

Use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers. A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html to understand more about routing.

In your case server.js should be

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Time:', Date.now())
    next()
});
// define the register page route
app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Registered user')
})
```

OR if you want to use the express.Router, it should be like this

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const register = require('./routers/auth_user_registration.js');
const login = require('./routers/auth_user_login.js');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(register);
app.use(login);

const port = 3060;
// server is listening on port 3060
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}..`);
});
```